# Converting Int16 to UByte[] is not working in C# with BitConverter.GetBytes()

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, compiler-construction

I am working on a super simple parser/compiler for an example language, and I am having some problems with number conversion. I have the following code as a test:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.GetBytes(0x010D)[0]);
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.GetBytes(0x010D)[1]);
```

And in the console it prints:

```
13
1
```

I am confused because that means that the array is [13, 1]. I would assume that it should go from left to right like the original number does. Is there a way to fix this or do I just need to always treat it like it goes the other way?

Thanks a lot!

P.S.
Apologies if this is dumb, I just can't seem to find anything with my problem, which may well be because this is a user error.

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=netcore-3.1#System_BitConverter_GetBytes_System_Int32_: "The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.". If you're not familiar with the concept of endianness, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! It would probably be good to put that as an answer if you don't mind, so I can mark this as solved/answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to answer this question because [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) commented with an appropriate answer.

The solution to this question is really quite simple, and it was just a quirk of working with bytes and binary that I was not aware of.

See:
[Endianness Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)
[GetBytes Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=netcore-3.1#System_BitConverter_GetBytes_System_Int32_)

Endianness essentially is which order the bytes in a number go in. In my case, with .NET, the numbers are little-endian, meaning that the smaller numbers come first, followed by the big numbers. For the question's example, `0x010D` would be represented as `{ 0x0D, 0x01 }` in little-endian, as it was. If it were to be represented in big-endian, however, it would be represented as `{ 0x01, 0x0D }`

Thanks again to Jon Skeet for your helpful comment!